# S3 on EC2 with IAM: Error NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

My application use s3 and running on EC2. The IAM is configured on the instance, so the auth happen keyless (without the access key and secret key).

I'm able to upload or download file using aws cli. However when I tried to perform download operation using aws-sdk-go, I get error below:

> AccessDenied: Access Denied
>   status code: 403, request id: F945BDB5410E1A00, host id: m74jJ8z/AEzdkaJkWKdIqPEwPIYPZfWnLLfa5UpEwHwaBcXOuXTPY1aw/u/5HGralKg+ewAWEJA=

I followed the official guide from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/credentials/ec2rolecreds/ and from this issue https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/430 but got the error above.

Below is my code:

```golang
s3UploadPath = config.GetString("upload assets to s3.bucket")
s3Config := aws.NewConfig()
s3Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors = aws.Bool(true)

session, err := session.NewSession(s3Config)
if err != nil {
    Logger.Fatal("Error initializing s3 uploader. " + err.Error())
    os.Exit(0)
}

// the upload code
uploader = s3manager.NewUploader(session)
res, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(s3UploadPath),
    Key:    aws.String(filename),
    Body:   f,
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error on upload. " + err.Error())
}

// then continue with the download code
```

Attached screenshot showing that the download and upload operations are success  through aws cli

[image]

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the entire `creds` section. Just don't pass credentials when creating the session. It will default to using the machine role.

Comment: @Adrian I removed the creds section, and then got different error. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this error by doing two things.

The first one is by using `stscreds.NewCredentials(session, roleArn)` as the credentials during session creation.

```golang
s3Config := aws.NewConfig()
s3Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors = aws.Bool(true)
s3Config.WithLogLevel(aws.LogDebugWithHTTPBody)
s3Config.Region = aws.String(region)
s3Config.WithHTTPClient(&http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    },
    Timeout: 10 * time.Second,
})

sess, err := session.NewSession(s3Config)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error initializing session. " + err.Error())
}

sess.Config.Credentials = stscreds.NewCredentials(sess, arn)
_, err = sess.Config.Credentials.Get()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error getting role. " + err.Error())
}
```

And the 2nd thing is by defining `NO_PROXY` environment variable with value is `169.254.169.254`. The particular IP is AWS global IP used for getting the EC2 metadata.

And since my application uses proxy to communicate with the S3 server, I need to exclude that IP.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to specify credentials when using IAM role on EC2 instance.

I see you are getting `Access Denied` which means your Go program is able to pick the EC2 profile creds but probably due to lack of permissions, its getting this error.

Reading your code, it seems you want to write object to S3. Can you make sure you have given `s3:Get*`, `s3:List*`, `s3:PutObject`, `s3:PutObjectAcl` to your IAM Role and there is no explicit Deny on S3 Bucket policy?

Comment: please see my updated answer. I'm able to perform list, get, and put operations through aws cli, but not able programatically using the sdk